# Error when using PSSession and Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-management-shell

So trying to run Exchange Management Shell Locally using PSSession, but getting an AD Operation Failure.

Here are my steps

1)open PSmodule as Admin

2)

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName DAG01 -Credential domain\user
```

3)

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn
```

4)

```
Search-Mailbox user -SearchQuery Subject:"anything" -EstimateResultOnly
```

This is where i get the error. ->

```
Active Directory operation failed on . The supplied credential for 'domain\user' is invalid.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ADInvalidCredentialException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=CHGDAG01,RequestId=4f848ef8-264c-4db7-a4e8-2acf2dae560f,TimeStamp=5/13/2016 4:45
```

:55 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ADInvalidCredentialException] 5533B753

Weird thing is that if I RDP with the same credentials into the DAG and run Exchange Management Shell, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be used to import a PSSession from your remote exchange server.

```
$Params = @{
    ConfigurationName = 'Microsoft.Exchange'
    ConnectionUri = "http://youexchangeserver.server.com/PowerShell/"
    Credential = ( Get-Credential )
    Authentication = 'Kerberos'
    Name = 'ExchangeSession'
}
Import-PSSession -Session ( New-PSSession @Params )
```

However, I am not understanding how yours is working so I would try this:

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName DAG01 -Credential $Credential
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn
```

I will note that if you're running PowerShell as the account that is performing the action, you do not need to even specify credentials.

Comment: That sounds correct but it doesn't work.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/connect-to-exchange-servers-using-remote-powershell?view=exchange-ps

Comment: The first part works but the second part doesn't.  It should but doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a `pscredential` object to the `-Credential` parameter.

You can use `$cred = Get-Credential` then `-Credential $cred`

[Get-Credential on technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849815.aspx)

Comment: `$User = "Domain01\User01";
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "P@sSwOrd" -AsPlainText -Force;
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord`

Answer (score 0):

$creds = Get-Credential

$sess = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://myserver.mydomain.com/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $creds

## Then do strictly Exchange commands with

Enter-PSSession $sess

Get-Mailbox xyz

Exit

## or do some PowerShell + Exchange stuff with

Import-PSSession $sess

Get-Mailbox xyz

.\DoSomthing.PS1

Remove-PSSession $sess

This is from info on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/connect-to-exchange-servers-using-remote-powershell?view=exchange-ps